# Сколько байт основного файлового потока может храниться непосредственно в MFT?

Tags: winapi, ntfs

Желательно со ссылкой на источник.

---

Я понял, что вопрос получился слишком абстрактным. Конкретизирую прикладную задачу: как для данного файла (пусть будет простой файл без ADS, сжатия и разрежения) определить кол-во байт, распределенных на томе, содержащем этот файл?

Comment: @karmadro4, Вы наверное уже видели [это](http://www.insidepro.com/kk/044/044r.shtml)?

Собственно заинтересовался т.к. не понял вопроса (что такое MFT (единственной ассоциацией была IBM 360) и о каких потоках идет речь ?). 

После взгляда на **это** от "ака мыщъх" хоть ясно стало, что речь об атрибутах (метаинформации) файлов NTFS, частично хранимых в Master File Table этой файловой системы.

Благодарю за просветительскую деятельностью.

Comment: @avp, так вы бы на метку `[ntfs]` взглянули ;-)

Судя по возврату от FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS, "малый" файл может быть помещен в MFT полностью, без распределения дополнительных блоков.

Comment: @karmadro4, а как Вы думаете, я нагуглил статью про NTFS ?

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [вот этому источнику](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), $Mft содержит блоки по 1кб на каждый файл, при этом в блоке хранится ACL, имя файла и атрибуты, и в случае, если в блоке 1кб осталось достаточно места, чтобы вместить все данные, для файла не выделяется дополнительного блока в файловой системе. Соответственно, чтобы определить, есть ли дополнительные блоки, нужно влезть в $Mft и достать список атрибутов файла (код на питоне для парсинга NTFS есть [тут](https://github.com/williballenthin/indxparse)), и проверить тип атрибута DATA - если он резидентный, значит, файл весь в MFT. Также есть [KB967351](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/967351), предназначенная для увеличения блока в $Mft до 4кб, если хотфикс установлен, `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo <диск>` покажет 4096 в строке "Bytes per FileRecord segment", в противном случае там будет 1024.

Если же файл не влезает целиком в MFT, для выяснения точного объема выделенного пространства придется лазать по файловым структурам (детали [тут](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2009/10/16/the-four-stages-of-ntfs-file-growth.aspx)), учитывая, помимо блоков для данных, записи MFT для хранения ссылок на фрагменты данных и блоки самого списка атрибутов (если они есть). Однако для простых (сплошных) файлов достаточно взять размер файла, поделить на размер кластера, прибавить 1, если есть остаток от деления и умножить назад на размер кластера. (И прибавить несколько килобайт на затраты в MFT, всё же, если файл не фрагментирован, одного хватит.)